# Printing the preparedStatement SQL after the bind for Oracle jdbc driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have tried several examples , but none of them seem to work. Here is the code I tried last

```
 import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
 PreparedStatement prs = null;
 ResultSet rrs = null;
Class stmt1 = null;
java.lang.reflect.Field mem = null;

  requestSQL = "Select FIPS_STATE_CD_TXT, FIPS_COUNTY_CD_TXT from MSTR_FIPS_COUNTY where STATE_ID = ? " + " and COUNTY_TXT = ?";

    prs.setString(1, vPropertyState);
    prs.setString(2, vPropertyCounty);
    System.out.println(prs.toString()); //JRN
             Class stmt1 = prs.getClass();  
          java.lang.reflect.Field mem = stmt1.getField("sql");  
          String value= (String)mem.get(prs);  
          rrs = prs.executeQuery();
```

I get an error on this at :

```
   Exception trying to make a TAF call
   java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: sql
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1520)
```

I even tried using this example from JavaWorld, but my compiler doesn't seem to recognize DebugLevel and StatementFactory. Is there a special package I should download for this?
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2002/jw-0125-overpower.html?page=3

I am using Java 1.6 and Oracle 11g. I am also looking for a quick fix, rather than installing log4jdbc or p6sy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, you can't. Atleast not for the Oracle jdbc driver.

Comment: Hecka bummer. Desirable feature. +1

Answer (score 4):

Different drivers use different names. In your case the `sql` field you are trying to access is not one of the available ones for that driver.

To get all the names of your JDBC driver use this code:

```
Class stmt1 = prepStmt.getClass(); 
try {
    java.lang.reflect.Field mem[] = stmt1.getDeclaredFields();  
    for (Field x:mem){
        System.out.println("Field:"+x.getName());
    }    
}  catch (SecurityException ex) {

}
```

Observe the field name, and then use your code above to print its value.

Comment: Hopefully you are still active. I'm not sure how to use his code after getting the field names using your code. I kept getting No field exception.

Comment: @carnal in the loop, x.getName() will return the name of the field in your table. For example 'ExpiryDate'. Then you can use the 'ExpiryDate' in your sql like 'SELECT ExpiryDate FROM tableName WHERE ......'

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible for `oracle` jdbc driver.
But in general some drivers ([mysql](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-a-prepared-statement-with-bind-variables-using-mysql.html)) supports this

`prs.toString()`

Comment: So, is there no way to print the preparedStatement for the oracle jdbc driver?

Comment: as far as i know, experts please advice if otherwise